# Mix of State Stores and Partitions on kafka stream instances

Tags: apache-kafka, apache-kafka-streams

I built a kafka streaming application with a state store. Now I am trying to scale this application. When running the application on three different servers Kafka splits up partitions and state stores randomly.

For example:

Instance1 gets: partition-0, partition-1

Instance2 gets: partition-2, stateStore-repartition-0

Instance3 gets: stateStore-repartition-1, stateStore-repartition-2

I want to assign one stateStore and one partition per instance. What am I doing wrong?

My KafkaStreams Config:

```
final Properties properties = new Properties();
properties.setProperty(StreamsConfig.APPLICATION_ID_CONFIG, "my-app");
properties.setProperty(StreamsConfig.BOOTSTRAP_SERVERS_CONFIG, BOOTSTRAP_SERVERS_CONFIG);

try {
     properties.setProperty(StreamsConfig.STATE_DIR_CONFIG,
           Files.createTempDirectory(stateStoreName).toAbsolutePath().toString());
} catch (final IOException e) {
         // use the default one
}
```

And my stream is:

```
stream.groupByKey()
       .windowedBy(TimeWindows.of(timeWindowDuration))
       .<TradeStats>aggregate(
           () -> new TradeStats(),
           (k, v, tradestats) -> tradestats.add(v),
           Materialized.<String, TradeStats, WindowStore<Bytes, byte[]>>as(stateStoreName)
        .withValueSerde(new TradeStatsSerde()))
        .toStream();
```

Comment: Please show us your declaration of `stateStoreName`. Is it perhaps some kind of `Stores.inMemoryKeyValueStore`?

Comment: I don't have any further definition of the stateStore except of the name. I guess by passing the name of the stateStore the stateStore gets created automatically. I got this from the kafka-streams-stockstats example (https://github.com/gwenshap/kafka-streams-stockstats).

Comment: Well then take a look into my answer down below. :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From what I can see so far (as mentioned in my comment to your question, please share your state store definition), everything is fine and I suspect a slight misconception on your side regarding the question

> What am I doing wrong?

Basically, nothing. :-)

For the **partition part** of your question: They get distributed around the consumers according to the configured assignor (consult https://kafka.apache.org/26/javadoc/index.html?org/apache/kafka/clients/consumer/CooperativeStickyAssignor.html or adjacent interfaces).

For the **state store part** of your question: May be here lies a little misconception on how (in memory) state stores work: They are usually backed by a Kafka topic which does not reside on your application host(s) but in the Kafka cluster itself. To be more precise, a part of the whole state store lives in the (RocksDB) in-memory key/value store on each of your application hosts, exactly as you showed in the state store assignment in your question. However these are **only parts** or slices of the complete state store which is maintained in the Kafka cluster.

So in a nutshell: Everything is fine, let Kafka do the assignment job and interfere with this only if you have really special use-cases or good reasons. :-) Kafka also assures correct redundancy and re-balancing of all  partitions in case of outages of your application hosts.

If you still want to assign something on your own, the use-case would be interesting for further help.